# Return multiple variables in a loop using dict()

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dictionary, return

I have edited the previous section, anything under the line below has been answered and is outdated now:

```
def foo():

    x = dict()
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        x[i] = i*2
        i + = 1
        yield x[i]
```

How do I call a specific instance of x[i] in a new function?

---

---

```
def foo():

    x = dict()
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        x[i] = i*2
        i + = 1
        return x[i]
```

I want this to return x[1],x[2],x[3]...x[10], but right now it only 
returns the final variable. The reason I want to do this is because
in my actual code, I won't know how many times the loop will iterate

```
def main():

    variable = foo()
    print variable
```

I'm just using this to prove to myself that it returned some values

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is this supposed to do?  `x*2` doesn't really make sense for `x = dict()` ...

Comment: @sshashank124 I fixed the (dumb) mistake with the x and the yield works! How do I call each separate value in a new function?

Comment: What do you mean by "each separate value in a new function"?

Comment: @sshashank124 I updated my main post, maybe that will help explain what I'm trying to say a little better. Say I want to use x[1] in another function, how would I call that specific variable in another function?

Comment: @sshashank124 Yes you've fully answered my question and I've got my program running now. Thank you very much! I hit the up arrow, and I just marked your answer as "accepted". I didn't know what the checkmark would do and then I saw your mention of it and understood immediately. Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that, consider using the `yield` expression:

```
def foo():
    x = dict()
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        x[i] = x*2
        i += 1
        yield x[i]

for i in foo():
    print i
```

As @Ismail said, it should be `i += 1` not `x += 1`

Also, what is `x*2` supposed to do? Did you mean `i*2`?

#### Example of using the `yield` expression

```
def next_one(i,n):
    while i < n:
        yield i
        i += 1

>>> for i in next_one(1,10):
...     print i
...
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

---

#### [Answer to question update]

You could do it something as follows using the `next()` operator:

```
def next_one(i,n):
    while i < n:
        yield i
        i += 1

def main(variable):
    print next(variable)

variable = next_one(1,10)
main(variable)
main(variable)
main(variable)

[OUTPUT]
1
2
3
```

Demo: http://repl.it/R6J